# How to evaluate theta function's derivative numerically?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, special-functions

I ran into this derivative that Mathematica won't evaluate:

```
ClearAll[f, g];
a = 0.1;
b = 0.2;
t = Exp[I 2 Pi/3];
f[z_] := SiegelTheta[{{a}, {b}}, {{t}}, z]
g[z_] = D[f[z], z]
g[0.1] // N
```

I am not sure if this derivative can be evaluated to a numerical value actually...

Comment: Which to accept will depend on the vote, for me both of them are excellent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Numerical derivative

Based on 
$$f'(z_0)={1 \over 2\pi i}\,\int_\gamma {f(z) \, dz\over (z-z_0)^2}\,,$$
where $\gamma$ is a closed contour containing $z_0$ in its interior.

```
fPrime[z0_] :=
  1/8 Sum[f[z0 + dz]/dz,
          {dz, Exp[2 Pi I Most@Subdivide[0., 1., 8]]/1000}];

fPrime[0.1]
(*  -0.256724 + 1.47096 I  *)
```

---

*Update:*

Discretizing the integral with `n = 2` points instead of `n = 8` yields the central difference formula, and for a radius of `Abs[dz] == 1*^-9`, it will have a truncation error less than machine-precision for analytic functions whose higher-order derivatives do not grow too rapidly.  To prevent round-off error overwhelming the truncation error, we compute `f[z]` at high precision.  This is faster than the 8-point machine-precision code above on the OP's function (I suspect because `SiegelTheta` is somewhat expensive to compute).  The 8-point formula with a radius of `1/1000` in `fPrime` has a relative error of $10^{-10}$ or less in a neighborhood of $z = 0.1 + 0i$. The function `ND[]` has a relative error of $10^{-5}$ or less. Over the square with `ReIm[z]` between `±1`, the relative errors of `fPrime` and `ND` can be a couple of orders of magnitude larger, but `fPrime2` below maintains machine-precision-accurate results.

```
ClearAll[f, fPrime2];
a = 1/10;
b = 2/10;
t = Exp[I 2 Pi/3];
f[z_] := SiegelTheta[{{a}, {b}}, {{t}}, z]
fPrime2[z_?NumericQ] := N@With[{z0 = SetPrecision[z, 32], r = 1*^-9},
    (f[r + z0] - f[-r + z0])/(2 r)
    ];
```

#### Symbolic derivative

For the OP's special case of `SiegelTheta[]`, a symbolic derivative can be computed from the `Sum[]` of its theta series expansion, which returns a sum in terms of `EllipticTheta[]`, whose derivative is implemented as `EllipticThetaPrime[[]`:

```
SiegelThetaPrime[{{a_}, {b_}}, {{t_}}, z_] = Simplify@D[
   Sum[Exp[
     I Pi ((n + {a}).{{t}}.(n + {a}) + 
        2 (n + {a}).(z + {b}))], {n, -Infinity, Infinity}],
   z]
(* 
(E^(-((I π (b + z)^2)/
  t)) π (-2 I (b + z) EllipticTheta[3, (π (b + a t + z))/t, 
     E^(-((I π)/t))] + 
   EllipticThetaPrime[3, (π (b + a t + z))/t, 
    E^(-((I π)/t))]))/(Sqrt[-I t] t)
*)

SiegelThetaPrime[{{1/10}, {1/5}}, {{Exp[I 2 π/3]}}, 0.1]
(*  -0.256724 + 1.47096 I  *)
```

Comment: I fail to see how your formula gives the derivative. In the Cauchy formula for the derivative the $z-z_0$ should be squared, and there should be $2\pi i$ instead of $2\pi$. What do I miss?

Comment: @mickep I forgot the square and the $i$ -- thanks!  (And the $dz$.)

Comment: Thanks, and nice! I was confused there for a while!

Comment: Indeed, one can express the [univariate case of `SiegelTheta[]` in terms of the more conventional Jacobi theta functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/21.2.iii).

Comment: As it turns out, there is an *undocumented* function for expanding out the genus-1 case of `SiegelTheta[]` in terms of `EllipticTheta[]`: ``D[SiegelTheta[{{a}, {b}}, {{t}}, z] // System`SiegelThetaDump`SimplifySiegelTheta, z]``.

Answer (score 7):

You can compute a numerical derivative as follows:

```
ClearAll[f, g];
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
a = 0.1;
b = 0.2;
t = Exp[I 2 Pi/3];
f[z_] := SiegelTheta[{{a}, {b}}, {{t}}, z]
g[z0_] := ND[f[z], z, z0]
g[0.1] 

(*-0.256725 + 1.47096 I*)
```

I haven't checked the result is correct.

Answer (score 2):

A quick-and dirty method is to use [complex-step differentiation](https://doi.org/10.1137/S003614459631241X):

```
With[{a = 1/10, b = 1/5, t = Exp[I 2 π/3], z = 1/10, h = 10^-9, prec = 20}, 
     N[(SiegelTheta[{{a}, {b}}, {{t}}, z + I h] -
        SiegelTheta[{{a}, {b}}, {{t}}, z - I h])/(2 I h), prec]]
   -0.2567239264794337275 + 1.4709617732598025465 I
```

where even a modest-sized step size can yield a slightly more accurate result, compared to using a purely real step size.

Alternatively, one can use Cauchy's differentiation formula. Michael's answer shows one possible implementation, and here is another one:

```
With[{a = 1/10, b = 1/5, t = Exp[I 2 π/3], z = 1/10, r = 10^-6}, 
     NIntegrate[SiegelTheta[{{a}, {b}}, {{t}}, z + r Exp[I u]]/(2 π r Exp[I u]),
                {u, -π, π}, Method -> "Trapezoidal", WorkingPrecision -> 20]]
   -0.2567239264794337266 + 1.4709617732598025411 I
```

Finally, one might also consider trying the ["Lanczos derivative"](https://doi.org/10.2307/2589707):

```
With[{a = 1/10, b = 1/5, t = Exp[I 2 Pi/3], z = 1/10, h = 10^-9},
     (3/(2 h^3)) NIntegrate[u SiegelTheta[{{a}, {b}}, {{t}}, z + u], {u, -h, h}, 
                            Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 20]]
   -0.25672392647943372659 + 1.4709617732598025411 I
```